# If $a_1a_2\cdots a_n =1$, then $\prod_{i=1}^n (1+a_i) \geq 2^n$

Tags: inequality, products, means, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

Let 
$$
a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n
$$
be positive real numbers such that
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n a_i =1
$$
Prove that 
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n (1+a_i) \geq 2^n
$$

Answer (score 12):

**Hint:** note that $\frac{1+a_i}{2} \geq \sqrt{a_i}$ (by the AM-GM inequality), so that
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1+a_i}{2}\right) \geq
\prod_{i=1}^n \sqrt{a_i}
$$

Answer (score 4):

By Holder $$\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i)\geq\left(1+\sqrt[n]{\prod\limits_{i=1}^na_i}\right)^n=2^n$$